# flutter show more text widget till number is 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I have app that get a number from user and calculated it with two equations, its keep doing the two equations till its equals to 0 by using while loop and then show the result, its work fine.

but I want to show every step each time do that equations in text, and show ovary step in new line.

I think of doing text widget as list and make the while loop but I stocked on that

the steps is like this

get the input from user
Please Enter a number Grater than 0

step one show user text "Result of the first Equation is: $result
step tow show user text Result of the second Equation is: $result

and it repeats the two steps till it equals to 1 then stop show user text the final result is 1 then

so how I can make that??

Screenshot added...

[image]

Comment: Please provide your homepage.dart file

Comment: If you store the steps in a list, you can easily display the contents of the list with something like a `Column`.

Answer (score 0):

I did it finally

I store all step messages in list

```
List<String> messg = [];
messg.add(messg1);
```

then I created a widget list for text widget and put all step messages in to the widget

```
  Widget getTextWidgets(List<String> string) {
    List<Text> list = string.map((text) => new Text(text)).toList();

    return new SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(children: list));
  }
```

so it works

thanks for all

[image]